# Reactjs - How to re-direct to default home page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to set redirection to default page, but not works. what is the correct way to do this?

```
const routes = [
    {
        path:"/",
        component:Home,
        extract:"true",
        redirect:"/home"
    },
    {
        path:"/home",
        component:Home
    },
    {
        path:"/service",
        component:Service
    }
];
```

html:

```
<div>
  <Router>
    <Header />
       {routes.map((route) => (
          <Route
            key={route.path}
            path={route.path}
            component={route.component}
          />
                    ))}
   </Router>
```

Comment: have you tried declare your route path with slash  `path="/home"` ?

Comment: @buzatto - no luck. page is not loading, getting same error. but landing page alone works when i put "/" instead of `home`

Comment: oh, your `<Header />` should be inside at Router to your router links work properly

Comment: it's worked after moving to header. it was cache issue. but when refresh page is not loading..

Comment: By nature, React was designed for single-page applications (SPA). As it grew in popularity, libraries like `react-router` were created to create the simulation of having multiple pages, but you must remember, there is actually only one endpoint. 

May I ask, why are you refreshing the page? Because most actions that trigger a refresh (`onSubmit`, `onClick`, etc) on a normal website are managed by React using the DOM with no need for a full page refresh.

Comment: you are correct. but when user refresh wrongly how can we show default page, instead where he were. ( there is just static page as well in the app )

Comment: I think that [Stjin de Witt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/286685/stijn-de-witt) addressed this issue with far better clarity and detail than I ever could. Please reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/users/286685/stijn-de-witt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using `react-router-dom`, I can see one definitive issue with some additional concerns. You may only need to make one change, but I would advise reviewing the rest of your code to ensure the best routing config.

Main Issue: You have to add a redirect to `'/home'` if you want that component to be the first page to be loaded. This is because when the app is rendered, it sees the default path as `'/'`.

```
<Redirect exact from="/" to="/home" />
  <Route path="/home">
    <Home />
  </Route>
```

While this may solve your problem by itself, here is a more comprehensive solution that should be beneficial to compare your current code against.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import home from "./Home";
import service from "./Service";
import header from "./Header";

function App () {


    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
        <Header />
        <hr />
          <Switch>
            <Redirect exact from="/" to="/home" />
              <Route path="/home">
                <Home />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/service">
                <Service />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </div>
      );
    }


export default App;
```

As you can see, I would recommend moving the Header outside of the `Switch` statement and then applying the redirect from `/` to `/home`.

Also, please note this configuration is simply an example. It depicts a situation where you are exporting `App` as a component and does not account for login authorization, so certain aspects of your code may vary.

Comment: After the build ( at present all are static pages ) I am loaded in to the chrome server, while i refresh still page is not loading. getting as `entry not found: /home` how to fix this? But all works fine with local host

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you meant by chrome server? What hosting platform are you using?

Comment: I am using chromes inbuild server, "http://127.0.0.1:8887/" -it's loading from here. otherwise imagine I use express, how to handle it?

Comment: I've personally never used that server, so I'm not certain of the configuration. However, what you are describing is likely caused by the lack of a server-side router (express, etc).  There are several ways to handle this, but in my experience when using `HashRouter` or `BrowserRouter` it usually helps to run what is called a "wildcard router" or "server router" on the backend. Here is [an article for reference](https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-router/#browser-history).